# Dense subset of the shifts of one point in Cantor space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $C=\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ with metric

$$d(x,y)=\Sigma_{i=1}^\infty\frac{\vert x_i-y_i\vert}{2^i}$$

be a model of the Cantor space.

It is clear that the subset of the following form
$$B_s=\{x\in C\mid x_i=s_i ~\text{for}~ 1\leq i\leq m \},$$
where $s=(s_1,\dots,s_m)\in\{0,1\}^m$ with $m\in \mathbb{N}$ is a finite sequence, form a basis for topology on $C$ generated by $d$.

A subset $A$ of a topological space $X$ is said to be dense in $X$ if the closure $\mathsf{Cl}(A)=X$.

Let $S:C\to C$ be the shifting map defined coordinate-wise as follows $S_i(x)=x_{i+1}$. Here $S^n$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$ denotes the composition of $S$ with itself $n-1$ times, e.g. $S^2=S\circ S$.

> I met an exercise asking to find a point $x\in C$ such that the set $\{S^n(x)\mid n\geq 1\}$ is dence in $C$.

I tried to figure it out but can not crack it yet.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your definition of metric  doesn't satisfy $d(x,y)=d(y,x).$ Maybe need absolute values...

Comment: Oh, thanks. It is typo, I fix it.

Comment: @amsmath Interesting, but why the set of shifts be dense in C, since for some n S^n reach the beginning of the finite sequence and hence will be in the basic open defined by the sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set consisting of all finite sequences is countable. Therefore we may define a sequence $x$ such that each finite sequence appears somewhere in $x$.

Given $y\in C$ and $\epsilon>0$, we find $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $\sum_{i>n}2^{-i} < \epsilon$. Let the finite sequence $(y_1,\ldots,y_n)$ be at position $m+1$ in $x$. Then, since $(S^mx)_i = y_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$ and $|(S^mx)_i-y_i|\le 1$ for $i>n$, we conclude that  $d(S^mx,y)\le \sum_{i>n}2^{-i} < \epsilon$.

Comment: isn't it true that $\vert\left(S^m(x)\right)_i-y_i\vert\le 1$ instead of $\vert\left(S^m(x)\right)_i-y_i\vert\le 2$, why do we need $2$?

Comment: @EvgenyKuznetsov Yes, sure. I forgot that $-1$ cannot appear. I'll change that.

Comment: Clever point! Thank you a lot.